# Page Transition How To

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a full page transition using @Keyframes and CSS3 only without JavaScript.

Now I am stuck with my codes. Wondering if it is possible when I click on the link it will create a full page transition that moves from bottom to upward like this: http://burtonfeelgoodsnowboard.com/test/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="moveTop">

<h1>Page</h1>

    <nav>       
        <a href="#" class="active">Page Up</a>

    </div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v4.3.0 | MIT License | http://h5bp.com/ */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

html {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

audio,
canvas,
img,
video {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}


body{
    font: 16px/1.5 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #3498db;
    color: #ffffff;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

span{
    color: #2980b9;
    font-weight: bold;
}


h2{
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
}


nav{
width: 28.09%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;

}

nav a {
    font-size: 19px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color: #2980b9;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 5px 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 2px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 10px;
border: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
border-radius: none;
}

nav a.active,nav a:hover {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    color: #3498db;

}


}


.moveTop{
    -webkit-animation: moveToTop .6s ease both;
    animation: moveToTop .6s ease both;
}

@keyframes moveFromTop {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
```

My JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6z5LsL6r/

Anyone who can show me the OUTPUT VIA JSFIDDLE?

Thank in advance guys!

Comment: Is this single page site? If not, you're gonna need Javascript I think.

Comment: If not just CSS can you show me some JSFiddle link for that? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:target` selector to work around: https://jsfiddle.net/6z5LsL6r/3/